# Semi-Norm on $L^1$ lower-semicontinuous on $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

is a semi-norm on $L^1(\Omega)$ lower-semicontinuous on $L^2(\Omega)$? Take for example the semi-norm

\begin{align*}
\varphi \colon L^1(\Omega) &\to \mathbb{R} \\
v &\mapsto \int_\Omega j(x) |v(x)| dx
\end{align*}

with a positive function $j \in L^\infty(\Omega)$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Use Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Your $\varphi$ is continuous on $L^1(\Omega)$, hence, it is continuous on $L^2(\Omega)$. Or did you want to ask about *weak* lower semicontinuity?

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. Since it is continuous, its lower semicontinuous (of course). The semi-norm is also convex and hence it is weakly lower semicontinuous! Thanks guys.